# How can I use the generated urls with the client's ip? Is that even possible?

Tags: node.js, express, ytdl

one of 'ytdl.getInfo()' properties is formats which every format has generated url
That URL can be used only in the server because it's linked with server IP.
YouTube Downloading Websites generate URLs like this but with my IP.
Can I generate the same URL but linked with the client's ip ?

Comment: Seems not implemented